# Running X without Access to /dev

Tags: x11, selinux

I am trying to run X on an unrooted Moto Z Play. For that I installed GNURoot which is running a limited version of Debian. One of the limits is that I can't access `/dev`. This causes `startx` and also `xinit` to fail, because it can't access `/dev/tty*`.
Is there any way to start X without that access?
On my old (rooted) phone, I was running Linux Deploy, which shared its desktop via VNC. Is anything similar possible without root and with the SELinux limitations in place?

Edit: I don't want X to access the phone's display hardware, I only want it to be available via VNC so I can access it via a VNC app pointed to `localhost`.

Comment: How exactly do you plan to let the X server access the display hardware if it doesn't have permissions to do so? If anyone could just bypass root permission restrictions, they wouldn't be restrictions. You can run a *second* X server that allows remote clients via VNC etc., but that one will also not be able to access the display hardware directly. Though you can run a client for it on your primary X server, of course.

Comment: I don't actually want it to access the display hardware directly, I just want to be able to access it using VNC. That's the way I had it setup on Linux Deploy. To view the display I'd just connect to localhost with a VNC app.

Comment: And to be able to access the hardware display in any way, via VNC or otherwise, you need root. Because if you want to run an X server that you can access via VNC, that X server in turn needs to access the display, if you want that. That you are not directly involved in the this when you use VNC doesn't change this fact.

Comment: Is there any way to do that without a hardware display? So just with some kind of virtual display?

Comment: @Dakkaron Xvfb provides an invisible X server that can be accessed with VNC or ssh. As it has a virtual display only, it does not need hardware access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the comments this is actually possible using `xvnc` or more precisely `xtightvncserver`. This starts a new X server without using `/dev` and forwards that to vnc.

The exact command is `tightvncserver -geometry 1920x1080 :51`.

To start a program (in this case the LXDE desktop environment) that is to be displayed on that virtual display use this command: `DISPLAY=localhost:51 lxsession -s LXDE &`

Comment: That's actually noy "contrary to the comments" (if you mean mine): "You can run a second X server that allows remote clients via VNC etc".